# SQL: Select Distinct [ColumnName] but return other columns too

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have the following **SignupInfo** table:

```
ID        UserID    FName     LName
--------------------------------------
ABC001    ABC       Albert    Einstein
DEF001    DEF       Isaac     Newton
ABC049    ABC       Albert    Einstein
DEF568    DEF       Isaac     Newton
GHI230    GHI       Thomas    Edison
```

I need to get `UserID`, `FName` and `LName` where only `UserID` is **DISTINCT**.

`SELECT DISTINCT UserID FROM SignupInfo` only gives me the `UserID` column but I need `FName` and `LName` too.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

The result should be:

```
UserID    FName     LName
----------------------------
ABC       Albert    Einstein
DEF       Isaac     Newton
GHI       Thomas    Edison
```

Comment: So `SELECT DISTINCT UserID,FName,LName   FROM SignupInfo`. You should normalise the `FName` and `LName` into a different table anyway probably.

Comment: So, if there are *multiple* rows with the same `UserID`, please give us a rule for *which* `FName` and `LName` values should be selected? We (and, in turn, SQL Server) need to be given a concrete rule. If the rule is something positional ("First", "Last", etc) then we also need to know how those positions are defined, based on your data.

Comment: 2 users could potentially have the same **FName** and **LName** but their **UserID** is unique.

Comment: If `UserID` is the primary key, it will always be unique...

Comment: See my answer below as I included example output.
If that's not what you need then you will need to clarify a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized I can simply do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT UserID, FName, LName FROM SignupInfo
```

since even if 2 users have the same **FName** and **LName**, their **UserID** will be different anyway.

The only problem in the database, in my opinion, is poorly maintained. I say that because I believe there should be a separate table with the users' UserIDs and FNames and LNames, so that the possibility of an operator misspelling a name in this table is eliminated.

To summarize with an example, if an operator enters this new row (notice that **Albert** is misspelt):

```
ID        UserID    FName     LName
--------------------------------------
ABC061    ABC       Albret    Einstein
```

then my **SELECT** statement above would return 2 rows with the same **UserID**.

Anyway, thanks for the suggestions guys!

Comment: Yeah, that database needs some normalizing.
Glad you have a workable solution.

Answer (score 2):

A GROUP BY may do what you want.

```
SELECT UserID, FName, LName FROM SignupInfo GROUP BY UserID, FName, LName;
```

I just recreated this on my own DB and here's the results of my query:

```
UserID  FName   LName
ABC Albert  Einstein
DEF Isaac   Newton
GHI Thomas  Edison
```

I think this does exactly what the OP asked for.
If he wants something else perhaps he needs to clarify.

Comment: This would still return Albert Einstein which does not fit the OP's criteria.

Comment: @BillGregg - I'm not sure what you're saying there. The OP hasn't given an expected output table, but based on their narrative, I expect 3 output rows with UserIDs `ABC`, `DEF` and `GHI`. I'd be remarkably surprised if the `ABC` row didn't have the name Albert Einstein (since there are two `ABC` rows in the source and they both have that name)

Comment: I believe this does exactly what he asked.

Comment: @Damien Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the post.  When taa said "I need to get UserID, FName and LName where only UserID is DISTINCT." I took that to mean that if there is only one UserID in the table.  BlackLight's answer is my interpretation of the question.

Comment: @BillGregg I see what you mean.
I guess we will have to get clarification from the OP as to which it is he actually wants.

Comment: @KemoSabe - Your solution works. And so does this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20149448/2246679

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - I'm sorry my question was not clear enough

Comment: @BillGregg - KemoSabe is right. I apologize for not being clear enough

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
select * from SignupInfo
where UserId in (select UserID from SignupInfo group by UserId having count(*) = 1)
```

**Edit - Example:**

```
declare @fred table (id varchar(max),UserID varchar(max),FName varchar(max),LName varchar(max))

insert into @fred values 
('ABC001',    'ABC',       'Albert'   , 'Einstein'),
('DEF001',    'DEF',       'Isaac'   ,  'Newton'),
('ABC049',    'ABC',       'Albert' ,   'Einstein'),
('DEF568',    'DEF',       'Isaac'  ,   'Newton'),
('GHI230',    'GHI',       'Thomas',    'Edison')

select * from @fred
where UserId in (select UserID from @fred group by UserId having count(*) = 1)
```

Comment: Please see the example.

Comment: `ID UserID FName LName
GHI230 GHI Thomas Edison`  
  
This is what I get with this query.  
The OP will need to clarify if this is what he wants or not.

Comment: Well... he could change the "select *" for "select {columns of choice}". I presumed he would be able to work that bit out.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that we want to select the values from the row which sorts earliest based on the `ID` column.

Then the query you want is:

```
;WITH Ordered AS (
  SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY ID) rn
  FROM SignupInfo
)
select UserID,FName,LName from Ordered where rn = 1
```

If there's some other sort order that should be preferred, just change the `ORDER BY` within the `OVER(...)` clause.

Answer (score 0):

This would get the job done:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(UserID), FName, LName
FROM SignupInfo
```

Comment: This gets the same results as my answer, which I believe is exactly what he expressed he needed.

Answer (score 0):

check this one

```
select Distinct userid,[Column2],[column003] from [table name]
```

Answer (score -1):

The query should look like this

```
SELECT UserID, FName, LName FROM SignupInfo GROUP BY UserID
```

Comment: No, this does not fit the OPs criteria.